# Running MVC 6 ASP.NET 5 localization example for dnx rc2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to run the AspNet5Localization example project from here https://github.com/damienbod/AspNet5Localization/tree/rc2

However, when I open the solution a warning box appears:

> DNX SDC version dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc2-16444 is required by your solution but is not installed on this machine. Do you want to install it now? If you select No, 'dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1' will be used as the solution DNX SDK version for this session.

I choose Yes.

Then another info box appears:

> DNX SDK version dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc2-16444 failed to install. The solution will use DNX SDK version dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1 for this session.

Because I have installed dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc2-16357 I change the "Soltion DNX SDK version" to 1.0.0-rc2-16357 from project properties.

```
Active Version           Runtime Architecture OperatingSystem Alias
------ -------           ------- ------------ --------------- -----
       1.0.0-rc1-update1 clr     x64          win
       1.0.0-rc1-update1 clr     x86          win             default
       1.0.0-rc1-update1 coreclr x64          win
       1.0.0-rc1-update1 coreclr x86          win
       1.0.0-rc2-16357   clr     x86          win
```

However, regardless this change, it fails to restore the packages.

I see the following error:

```
System.ArgumentException: More than one runtime.json file has declared imports for 'win7-x86'
Parameter name: runtimeName
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.RestoreCommand.FindRuntimeDependencies(String runtimeName, List`1 runtimeFiles, Dictionary`2 effectiveRuntimeSpecs, HashSet`1 allRuntimeNames, Func`2 circularImport)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.RestoreCommand.FindRuntimeDependencies(String runtimeName, List`1 runtimeFiles, Dictionary`2 effectiveRuntimeSpecs, HashSet`1 allRuntimeNames)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.RestoreCommand.<RestoreForProject>d__69.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.RestoreCommand.<>c__DisplayClass68_0.<<Execute>b__2>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.RestoreCommand.<Execute>d__68.MoveNext()
----------
Restore failed
More than one runtime.json file has declared imports for 'win7-x86'
```

How can I compile and run this example project?

Answer (score 4):

> How can I compile and run this example project?

**One**. Run the following three commands from the command line. This upgrades our `dnvm` and adds the recent development releases. Make sure to turn off anti-virus; my anti-virus blocked several .NET files.

```
set DNX_UNSTABLE_FEED=https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetcidev/api/v2
dnvm upgrade -unstable
dnvm install 1.0.0-rc2-16549 -runtime coreclr -unstable
```

**Two**. Open `AspNet5Localization/src/AspNet5Localization/project.json`. Add the following dependency. This fixes the runtime.json error. It does that by providing runtime information required to resolve target framework, platform, and runtime specific implementations of .NETCore packages.

```
 "Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms": "1.0.1-*"
```

**Three**. Open `AspNet5Localization/NuGet.config`. Make sure that the asp.nuget.org and nuget.org feeds are NOT commented out. Those feeds provide us with Newtonsoft.Json, Remotion.Linq, Ix-Async, and some Microsoft.CodeAnalysis packages. When you are done, the NuGet.config looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <!--To inherit the global NuGet package sources 
        remove the <clear/> line below -->
    <clear />
    <add key="MyGet aspnetcidev" 
         value="https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetcidev/api/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="api.nuget.org" 
         value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="nuget.org" 
         value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

At this point, `dnu restore` will now work but `dnu build` will not.

**Four**. Open `AspNet5Localization/src/AspNet5Localization/Controllers/BoxesController.cs`. [Responds to recent renaming](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/153) by finding and replacing the following.

```
HttpNotFound --> NotFound
HttpBadRequest --> BadRequest
```

**Five** Restore and build the `AspNet5Localization/src/Localization.SqlLocalizer` project.

```
$ cd src\Localization.SqlLocalizer
$ dnu restore
$ dnu build
```

**Six** Restore and build the `AspNet5Localization/src/AspNet5Localization` project.

```
$ cd src\AspNet5Localization
$ dnu restore
$ dnu build
$ dnx web
```

You will see the following result.

[image]

**Note 01**. This is what `dnvm list` looks like on my machine:

```
Active Version           Runtime Architecture OperatingSystem Alias
------ -------           ------- ------------ --------------- -----
       1.0.0-rc1-update1 coreclr x64          win
       1.0.0-rc2-16549   clr     x86          win             default
  *    1.0.0-rc2-16549   coreclr x64          win
```

**Note 02**. When you build, you will get two warnings that Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGeneration and Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGenerators.Mvc do not support dnx451. To get rid of those errors, open project.json. Either delete those two dependencies or delete the dnx451 framework.

Comment: Shaun, thanks for the elaborate answer. I was walking through your instructions and got stuck at `dnu restore` with the following error `NotFound https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetcidev/api/v3/flatcontainer/remotion.linq/index.json Unable to locate Dependency Remotion.Linq >= 2.0.2` it seems there is nothing here `https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetcidev/api/v3/flatcontainer/remotion.linq/index.json` might it be possible that something is broken?

Comment: Aha. Yes. Those were in my NuGet local cache. We need one more step, which I have now added to my answer.

Comment: @feradz I am also added another step, which is to build the `Localization.SqlLocalizer` before building the `AspNet5Localization` project.